# What is the 10-digit combination of Sherlock's locker?

Tags: mathematics

Sherlock made an elaborate code to remember the 10-digit combination to his locker. This is the code he came up with:

A-K-B-J-C-H-D-G-E-F

Each letter stands for a single digit number (0-9) When two numbers are written together without an operation symbol, they represent a tens digit and a ones digit. Two letters that are written with a slash between them represent a fraction.

D+D+D=F H+H=B
G+B+E=F+A+C
J+A=CC
FxD=KG
B÷H=K
DxH=CK
AxH=KE
J÷D=K
D/J = H/B

**What is the 10-digit combination to Sherlock's locker?
Show all your work.**

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: If I understand properly the puzzle C=1. Is it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We note that

> H + H = 2H = B, so H/B = 1/2. Then D/J = 1/2, so J/D = 2. Hence **K = 2**. We therefore also have a bunch of doubling pairs: 1-2, 2-4, 3-6, 4-8. But K=2, so J and D are either 3-6 or 4-8. Note that J&D are one set, and H&B are the other distinct set. Further, D and F are a tripled pair. Note that F = 3D, so D = 1,2,3. But from above, D=3,4, so **D = 3**. Then **J = 6** and **F = 9.** Further, HB must be the other double pair available, 4-8. Hence **H = 4** and **B = 8**. Now, F x D = 9 x 3 = 27 = KG, so **G = 7**. Since J = 6 and J + A = CC, J+A < 16 so CC = 11 and **C = 1**. Further, **A = 5**. Then A x H = KE => 5 x 4 = 2E = 20, so **E = 0**.

The code is A-K-B-J-C-H-D-G-E-F, which translates to

> 5-2-8-6-1-4-3-7-0-9.

Answer (score 3):

A more direct solution:

> 3D = F.  Therefore {D,F} is one of {1,3}, {2,6} or {3,9}.
>  DxF = KG.  We can extend {D,F,KG} = {1,3,03}, {2,6,12} or {3,9,27}.
>  The first 2 possibilities have duplicate digits, F=G or D=G, they are out.
>  Remains: K=2, D=3, G=7, F=9.
>  From there: J/D=K => J/3=2 => J=6
>  J+A=CC => C=1 and 6+A = 11 => A=5
>  DxH=CK => 3xH=12 => H=4
>  AxH=KE => 5x4=2E => E=0
>  and D/J=H/B => 3/6=4/B => B=8

This translates to the code:

> A-K-B-J-C-H-D-G-E-F = 5-2-8-6-1-4-3-7-0-9

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, +1! But please do be reminded to check others' answers before posting to avoid duplicates. Thanks!

Comment: This is a nice solution as well! I had figured that your starting point was probably faster but that was after I was halfway through. Great job! :D

Comment: The solution is the same, of course, but the way to arrive at the solution is just as important.

Comment: "The first 2 possibilities have duplicate digits, [...] they are out." I see absolutely nothing in the problem statement hinting that this should be true, and this assumption is unnecessary to arrive at the solution.

Comment: You are right.  I assumed different letters represent different digits.  Indeed, I can do without the assumption: 2H=B => B÷H=2 => K=2.  But that is inspired from El-Guest's answer.

Answer (score -1):

> 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
> -
> E   C   K   D   H   A   J   G   B   F

Comment: Hi, welcome to puzzling stack exchange! Please put your answer in spoiler tags, and provide an explanation as to how you got the answer. For more information and a badge, take the tour!